# Django + DatabaseError: Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type

Tags: django, django-models, gis, postgis, geodjango

I am having some issues with GeoDjango, Postgis and Postgres. I have a model with a PointField on called `pnt`, this contains the lng lat of an item.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    pnt = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
```

I am simply trying to search for items within a certain distance of another point using

```
from core.models import Profile
from django.contrib.gis.geos import fromstr
pnt = fromstr('POINT(1.139696 52.049925)', srid=4326)
Profile.objects.filter(pnt__distance_lt=(pnt, 1000000000))
```

But I am getting this error from the database.

```
DatabaseError: Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type
```

I have tried swapping the coords around when creating my pnt

```
pnt = fromstr('POINT(52.049925 1.139696)', srid=4326)
```

But this doesn't work either, so I am a little loss, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where does the error happen? After the distance filter? Try a more realistic filter distance, since a billion metres wraps around the earth's equatorial circumference nearly 25 times.

Comment: I've tried it with less distance. I have managed to pin point certain lat lngs that are causing this error to be thrown. 30.572269, 104.066541 doesn't work for example, whereas it would work happily with 51.5137073, -0.1922771.

Comment: Obviously 30.572269, 104.066541 will give an error! There is no such latitude 104.066541, so I think you have your axis order reversed.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm getting the same problem.